# How to translate IE dialog messages (shown in document check out/discard changes)

Tags: 2010, localization

I am working on translating an SharePoint 2010 website and one of the things that is driving me crazy is finding a way to translate IE dialog messages. Does anybody already had this problem? Please check the screenshot below.

I am using SharePoint 2010, with Language Packs installed (Japanese and Spanish). Testing with Internet Explorer 9. My system language is set to en-US.

[image: IE Dialog not translated]

Update #1:

1. Using Google Chrome the same messages were displayed correctly (in Japanese).
2. After installing system Japanese language packs and IE language pack the problem persisted

This problem keeps unsolved :(

Answer (score 1):

There may be some options that you can try out.

1. May be you can install an additional language pack of Japanese or Spanish to IE and check out these dialog boxes again. The installation is pretty straight forward - http://www.ehow.com/how_2033270_translate-internet-explorer.html. This option should allow displaying sites in different languages with changes in address and menu bar but does not guarantee on dialog boxes.
2. Did you try changing your system language?

Also read [this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-vista/Change-your-Internet-Explorer-language-settings) where it says, "To change the language used for Internet Explorer's menus and buttons, you need to install a version of Internet Explorer that is written in the language you prefer."

Comment: Thanks Deepu but I tried both and sadly didn't work. Maybe installing Office 2010 language pack would solve this problem but I have to pay $25 to buy the Japanese language pack and I will not pay to try something that may not solve my problem. I will keep this question open until I find a solution.